# NotSerializableException org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase

Tags: mongodb, neo4j, apache-storm

I am working with neo4j to create graph, taking data from mongodb as document. Standalone code is working fine without storm. But while integrating it with storm, I am getting -

> java.io.NotSerializableException: org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase

exception. Dont know the exact reason why i am getting this. If anybody faced such issue please let me know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to pass an object to the serializer that does not implement [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface.

Comment: I am not serializing  anything. But i too had the same thought so i serialized all classes which is getting used. Still i am getting the same exception.

Comment: @shaw.ram Seems that `neo4j` takes some class somewhere and tries to serialize it but fails. So check the documentation of it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to share more details. Most probably you're trying to serialize a Neo4j `Node` or `Relationship` object which holds a reference to a non-serializable `GraphDatabaseService`.

Comment: From bolt in execute method, i was calling method to create the graph and passing parameter as document which i was getting from mongodb and GraphDatabaseService object. Now i am passing only document as parameter. I am now creating GraphDatabaseService object in the static block of class where i am creating the graph. Issue is resolved. Thanks Michael for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

All classes that are used for attributes/fields in Storm must implement the interface `Serializable`. I assume that you are using a object of type `EmbeddedGraphDatabase` within `Collector.emit(new Values(...))` (either directly or in a nested way).

Comment: EmbeddedGraphDatabase is the API of Neo4j which is not implementing Serializable interface. I am using it into the bolt while loading to create it's object only once. But at runtime getting NotSerializable exception. Can You tell, what to do to work with such API do not inplement Serializable interface into storm.

Comment: I guess you have a class member variable of type `EmbeddedGraphDatabase`. If you initialize this variable not on the client but after the topology got deployed (ie, in open() or prepare()), you can simple declare the member `transient` which excludes is from serialization.