# java.io.NotSerializableException: com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl error

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-storm

Application reads data from kafka and writes into mongoDB.

below is the error line i am seeing...

`java.io.NotSerializableException: com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl`

Main class where topology starts.

```
ZkHosts zkHosts=new ZkHosts("localhost:2181");
String topic_name="test";
String consumer_group_id="storm";
String zookeeper_root="";
SpoutConfig kafkaConfig=new SpoutConfig(zkHosts,topic_name, zookeeper_root, consumer_group_id);
kafkaConfig.scheme=new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
KafkaSpout kafkaSpout = new KafkaSpout(kafkaConfig);
//Mongo Setup
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "zz.yyy.xx.abc",27017 );
mongoClient.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.SAFE);
MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("IOT");
MongoCollection<Document> iotSampleColl = db.getCollection("iot_sample");
MongoInsertBolt  mongoInsertBolt  = new MongoInsertBolt(iotSampleColl);
TopologyBuilder builder=new TopologyBuilder();
builder.setSpout("KafkaSpout", kafkaSpout);
builder.setBolt("MongoInsertBolt", mongoInsertBolt).allGrouping("KafkaSpout");
Config conf = new Config();
LocalCluster cluster=new LocalCluster();
try{
    cluster.submitTopology("test", conf, builder.createTopology());
    cluster.shutdown();
}catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

class which writes into MongoDB, MongoInsertBolt.class:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2504213456001787553L;
protected MongoCollection<Document> iotSampleColl;

public MongoInsertBolt(MongoCollection<Document> iotSampleColl) {
    this.iotSampleColl = iotSampleColl;
}

@Override
public void execute(Tuple tuple, BasicOutputCollector basicOutputCollector) {
    String word=tuple.getString(0);
    Document packet = new Document();
    packet.put("IOT_trans",word);
    if((null == word) || (word.length() == 0))
    {
        return;
    }
    iotSampleColl.insertOne(packet);
    System.out.println("Word is..."+word);
}

@Override
public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer outputFieldsDeclarer) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

Let me know if i am doing any mistake. Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: Does `MongoCollectionImpl` implements `java.io.Serializable`?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, no it is not.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, but i observed IComponent(BaseBasicBolt) is implementing serializable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33871998/notserializableexception-org-neo4j-kernel-embeddedgraphdatabase/33873342#33873342

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, i added transient keyword to iotSampleColl. then i am not facing serialization issue but facing NullPointer Exception at
iotSampleColl.insertOne(packet); do you have any idea sir?

Comment: If you mark a member "transient" it is excluded from serialization and initialized as `null` at de-serialization. Thus, this behavior is expected. I never worked with MongoDB and I am not sure why you give iotSampleCol via constructor -- does it contain any actual data? Can you initialize `iotSampleColl` in Bolt.prepere(...)? (move MongoSetup code into prepare method instead of submission code part)

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, thanks it not solved the problem completely but i am able to progressed a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move your MongoDB connection code into `prepare(...)` method:

```java
public class MongoInsertBolt extends IBasicBolt {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2504213456001787553L;
    protected MongoCollection<Document> iotSampleColl;

    @Override
    public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context) {
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "zz.yyy.xx.abc",27017 );
        mongoClient.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.SAFE);
        MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("IOT");
        iotSampleColl = db.getCollection("iot_sample");
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Tuple tuple, BasicOutputCollector basicOutputCollector) {
        String word=tuple.getString(0);
        Document packet = new Document();
        packet.put("IOT_trans",word);
        if((null == word) || (word.length() == 0))
        {
            return;
        }
        iotSampleColl.insertOne(packet);
        System.out.println("Word is..."+word);
    }

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer outputFieldsDeclarer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: you are amazing. i thought to do like this in my sleep last night. I hope it works. Thanks.

Comment: what is this approach, http://storm.apache.org/documentation/storm-jdbc.html. is it the actual way to use database connections in a better way? and connection pool?

Comment: Never used this and don't know the internals of the code.

Comment: That's okay, Thanks Matthias.